# Software Center Shows "Minus" Sign for Source Code....potential concern?

Tags: software-center, source-code

I realize there has been a previous post concerning this issue.  I am not clear as to what needs to be done about it.  If necessary, how do I go about removing the incomplete source code in the most effective manner to re-instate the "check mark"?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're a programmer who's interested in the source code of the applications, there is absolutely *no need* for you to have *any* source code on your system.

(For the critical eyes: yes I know about kernel headers, but that is not what the OP is talking about...  If yes, I'll delete my answer.)